# What does a basis rotation correspond to physically for linear position-momemtum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, reference-frames, double-slit-experiment, rotation

For polarization and angular momentum, rotating the basis corresponds to a very straightforward physical transformation, namely, the physical rotation of an experimental apparatus about an axis in space.  But what is the corresponding physical transformation corresponding to a rotation of basis for linear position-momentum?  For example, consider a two-slit apparatus.  Rotating the basis cannot correspond to rotating the slits.  That just transforms the measurement of position along one axis to position along a different axis.  It is not a transformation of measuring position to measuring momentum.  To measure momentum you have to measure wavelength, which means transforming the slits into a diffraction grating or something like that, but that's as far as I've gotten in figuring this out myself.

Comment: Its worth looking at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312834/experimentally-measure-velocity-momentum-of-a-particle-in-quantum-mechanics. These answers remind us that measurement in quantum physics, just like classical physics, is a messy business involving modelling of how your particular measurement device works.