# Are spacetime coordinates the only "thing" experiments can measure?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements

Since we live in a 4D world (3 of space and 1 of time, my question extends to more, if there are any) does this mean the only "thing" experiments measure are spacetime coordinates and the rest of the variables/quantities have to be calculated by the relation between the variables and spacetime coordinates?

**Examples**

- Velocity can be easily calculated from position and time measurements
- Kinetic energy
- Charge (using Coulomb's law and measuring the distance between charges)
- Mass (by measuring how the length changes for the spring)

Is there a quantity that can be measured "directly" without measuring position or time?

Comment: I think you have to define your definitions of "directly" more rigorously for this question. A photodiode connected to a voltmeter. Is the photodiode enough to count as direct measurement? Or do you include the readout for human senses? And if you do, does it make a difference if it is a digital readout made of semiconductors vs an analog one made of mechanical parts?

Comment: And what constitutes "position" to you? Hear me out, You can measure current by running it through a resistor, and then measuring the voltage using nothing but semiconductors by amplifying it, and feeding it to an analog-to-digital converter which then drives an ADC. No mechanical parts and just choose an ADC architecture that does not rely on time measurements. For example, one relies on sampling the voltage with a capacitor and then redistributing it between capacitors of known ratios. Does locating charge in different places count as position when you don't care about distance?

Comment: I would challenge the assertion that spacetime coordinates are measurable. How exactly would you use measurements to determine your $x$-coordinate right now? Coordinates are arbitrary labels, and nature couldn't care less how we label things. If you can clarify what you really mean by measuring spacetime coordinates, then maybe that would help clarify the question overall.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly. I agree that coordinates are just labels. What I mean here is that we choose some inertial frame and we measure coordinates wrt to it.

Comment: @DKNguyen but isn't current  density just amount of charge passing through unit area per unit time so aren't we indirectly measuring drift velocity of charges? Though I don't really know how should I define directly.

Comment: @mum Well, first of all, Current is the movement of the charge or wave and travels much faster than drift velocity which is the movement of the electrons. But then you would just say aren't I measuring the position of the wave in space. But you brought up another reason your question is a nebulous as defined. If my measurement process does not include measuring displacements or coordinates at all what does that qualify as? What if I'm just doing something like counting photons?

Comment: @DKNguyen But even to count photon we have to get them localised within certain region of space so again you are measuring "position" of photons .

Comment: @mum So it sounds, according to your interpretation of things, your question is just answered trivially by "yes because two things can't exist in the same place at the same time and something has to reach your sensor to measure it" which while answering your question also defeats the intent of the question. But I would argue measuring what is happening at some location is not the same as measuring position.

Comment: How about temperature?

Comment: @DKNguyen I think you said it right. this is precisely what I mean. To measure anything it has to reach the detector which is essentially measurement of its position.

Comment: @mum That's just causality and locality to be honest. Not very interesting IMO.

Comment: @DKNguyen if I try to phrase it in terms of math I know it will be, since all measurement devices we have exist in coordinate space , coordinates are the only thing we can measure. Like we cannot put a device in momentum space (?). And even to describe what is happening at someplace is measuring the distribution of things in space at different times and interpreting that distribution appropriately. For example to describe a wave passing a point we have to measure the displacement of something that is affected by the wave. Sorry if I am unable to put myself clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Measurements evolved when humans developed from primates and started cultivating to supplement hunting and gathering. Then it became important to have an exact definition of quantities of produce, dimensions of fields etc etc and the "money" for produce system developed.

Geometry with its theorems was the first modeling of nature ordering the measurements of fields and predicting new measurements. The coordinates as such are arbitrary, it is the mathematical functional relationships that constrain the model.

Your examples are examples of the use of a theoretical model that can fit the data and be predictive, using space and time coordinates. There are more sophisticated models that use energy and momentum to predict a plethora of data in complicated experiments.

The data are not only measurements of space and time, as discussed in the comments, there are now complicated methods of getting numbers by experiment that can be fitted with models, the models have to be  predictive to have any validity.

Comment: See for example this answer . https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/316004/244281 here we have to , in the end, rely on the measurement of radius of circular path of charge to measure momentum. Could you cite an experiment where we measure momentum or energy without actually using data of position ?

Comment: In accelerators, where the geometry is fixed and introduced into the programs that gather the detector signals, also with fixed locations, etc etc In the link you give, there are programs using already mapped locations , not measuring locations.